# Why is the actual memory usage in task manager different from the theoretical memory usage for C?

Tags: c, global-variables, global

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
typedef struct kk {
  char k[1000000];
} uuuu;
uuuu k[1000];
int main() {
  sleep(100);
  return 0;
}
```

The theoretical memory usage for this program should be [sizeof char(1Byte)* 1000000*1000];

However, the actual memory usage is only 961KB!

And since the global variable should be initialize to 0, all of the space should be memory in use.

Who can explain that?

Comment: Two semi obvious options I can see, either it counts on virtual memory always being first initialized to zero by the OS so it's not physically allocated until needed, or since you don't use the variables they're just optimized away.

Comment: Yeah, check out your linker map file.